# Socket Set TimeOut make app crash / Try reconnect is connection is lost

Tags: java, android, sockets, exception, client

I'm doing a project for receiving data from a server. This code works ok until I add the soTimeout line for the socket.

```
package com.lumineria.mywatertankr3;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String SETTINGS_PREF = "MyTankSettings";

TextView textViewNivel,textViewEstado;
String strNivel = "";
String ipAddressSaved="";

// Create the Handler object (on the main thread by default)
Handler handler = new Handler();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textViewNivel = findViewById(R.id.nivel);
    textViewEstado = findViewById(R.id.status);

    // Restore preferences
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS_PREF, 0);

    // Levanto de memoria los valores de IP y Tiempo de Refresco
     ipAddressSaved = settings.getString("ip", "");

    // SI tengo un valor definido de IP intento la conexion
    if (!ipAddressSaved.equals(""))
    {
        Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ClientThread());
        clientThread.start();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "No se definio IP del Server",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}


public class ClientThread  implements Runnable  {
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                InetAddress serverAddr = 
InetAddress.getByName(ipAddressSaved);
                 Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 10000);
// WHEN I ADD THIS LINE APP CRASHES
                // socket.setSoTimeout(10000);



                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader (socket.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( reader);
                String line;




                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                   strNivel = line;
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            textViewNivel.setText(strNivel);
                        }
                    });

                }
                in.close();
                socket.close();
                Thread.sleep(500);

            }
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException exception)  {
            textViewEstado.setText(textViewEstado.getText()+"1");
        } catch (IOException exception)  {
            textViewEstado.setText(textViewEstado.getText()+"2");
        } catch (Exception exception){
            textViewEstado.setText(textViewEstado.getText()+"3");
        }  finally {
            textViewEstado.setText(textViewEstado.getText()+"4");
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            Intent intent=new Intent(this,SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}



}
```

What I'm doing wrong? Is there a best way to check if server is no longer available? I want to check when nothing more is coming I prefer to disconnect and restart the connection.

THanks in advance

Comment: What is the stack trace associated with the crash?

Comment: I just solved the crash issue. It was related to try to access the textView from the catch. I  put the setText inside a handler.post(new Runnable() and it works. Anyway I want to reconnect after the exception. Can I create a new Thread? What is the best option?

Comment: Best option? That's subjective. If you want to get things rolling, note that your exception handlers take you outside your `while(true)` loop. If the loop surrounded the `try...catch` block, instead of the other way around, you could reconnect all day long.

Comment: Thanks greeble31. I resolved it starting again the thread. Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ClientThread());
                    clientThread.start();